# check the token expiration time in angular 4 the token isn't JWT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, jwt

i work on angular 4 as  frontend for  asp.net web api  backend  where  authentication and authorization is based  on token that  generated  from OAuth server  and as authentication matter i want to check the received token expiration token  .....and  i want  to know   if expiration time  is encoded  into  that token .
thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using asp.net identity, then requesting a token will give you an object containing the `token`, `token_type`,`.expires` and etc, You can reference the `.expires` property to know when your token is gonna expire

Comment: This project can help you [Link](https://github.com/VahidN/ASPNETCore2JwtAuthentication)

Comment: @John Velasquez   is there away to check if it  is valid or  not in angular 4 and  mark it as not authenticated  token .....thanks

Comment: @ Mohammad Dalir   thanks  i will check it

Comment: Just compare it to the current date, and do all the logic

Comment: @Mostafa don't forget that checks in a front-end application are useless in a security standpoint. And is only done for creating a better user experience. Like for example checking if a token is going to be expired soon and already requesting a new one so the user is never unauthenticated.

Checking if a token is valid/non expired should happen on your back-end. 

Your question cannot be answered without knowing which type of token you have. For example a 'reference token' doesn't contain any information in the token. Here you can solve your problem with a request to your OAuth server.

Comment: @ ErazerBrecht of  course i will i can  make  my question more specific  if  i use jwt  token  i can check expire  authenticate  using angular-jwt  module with help of jwthelper  service  but i use bearer  from OAuth server is  there an  methodology to  do that  with my token